# cross compiling error

Tags: cross-compiling

I try to cross compile an application to be run on arm target (my host is x86 ubuntu 11.10).

when i run "make", i obtain this error:

```
mar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/App$ make
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/GL/" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/c++/4.6/" is unsafe for cross-compilation
cc1plus: warning: include location "/usr/include/qt4/" is unsafe for cross-compilation
..
/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:77:15: fatal error: GL: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I know that i need to cross compile my librairies qt4 and OpenGL for arm , but i do not know how.

for makefile i use those compilers.

```
CC = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CXX = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
AR = ar
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply `libGL.a` for the architecture you're cross-compiling for.

To do that, discover whether is there `libGL.a` in your SDK or get it somewhere else, then use option `-L/path/to/your/arm/libs/dir` (also `-I/path/to/your/arm/headers` would be helpful).

To avoid searching in the native (host's) directories, use `-nostdlib` and `-nostdinc` (for GCC/G++)

Comment: it helps me.. But if I want to use `pkg-config` without externally providing the Include and Libraries. How can I do that?